# How can I use Windows in Ubuntu (not virtualized) to run an Adobe program?

Tags: windows, 18.10

I would like to use Windows (not virtualized) on a system based on Ubuntu 18.10. I need to use some Adobe program that I cannot use on Ubuntu, but at the same time I want the security that only Ubuntu can provide.

So I was thinking that I could run my Ubuntu system and within it run a Windows system, as there would be something like a "main system" (Ubuntu) from which I could use Windows. Is it possible?

I know that using Ubuntu (as an app) on Windows is possible, but I would like to know if the opposite is possible too.

Thanks!

Comment: There's wine and there's VM's and there's dual boot, but Ubuntu is not Windows.

Comment: You might be over-estimating the security of Ubuntu and of other Linux distributions. Windows can be made quite secure and the *bsd distributions are arguably more secure than any Linux distribution. A really large part of your security is what applications (e.g. firefox) you install and how you configure them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What you are asking is not possible

There is virtualization, which you do not want.

There is [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), a compatibility layer that translates Windows API calls to POSIX API calls. This allows some Windows software to work within Ubuntu. However, this is not real Windows and some Windows applications do not work in Wine.

Here are some analogies to help you understand. You want to drive a car inside a boat.

- The best you can do is put the car in a ferry. You can drive the car up and down the ferry as long as there is space in the ferry. This is virtualization.
- The second best is you can put a steering-wheel and brake and gas
  pedals inside your boat. This is Wine.

  1. When you turn the steering-wheel it will not turn the front wheels left or right, as boats don't have front wheels. But it will turn the rudder and you will have same effect: the boat will turn.
  2. When you press the gas pedal the boat will go faster.
  3. When you hit the brake, nothing will happen, as boats don't have
     brakes!

Hope this helps